# KnockoutJS - how to remove an object from an observableArray when remove is not a function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a structure of an array with a nested array. I am trying to remove an item from the nested array but I get the error that "remove is not a function".

I've recreated the problem in a simple jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rswailes/gts5g/ and also pasted the code below.

It's possible that the way I have set up the observables is not correct, but I'm stumped.

This is my html:

```
<script id="bookGroupTemplate" type="text/html">
    <br/>
    <h3><span data-bind="text: group_name"></span></h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>        
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "bookRowTemplate", foreach: books}'></tbody>        
    </table>
</script>

<script id="bookRowTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: author"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: genre"></td>        
    </tr>
</script>


<h1>Books!</h1>

<div data-bind='template: {name: "bookGroupTemplate", foreach: bookGroups}'></div>

<br/><br/>
<button data-bind="click: function(){viewModel.handleButtonClick(); }">Move One From Now to Later</button>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var BookGroup = function(group_name, booksToAdd){
    var self = this;

    this.group_name = ko.observable(group_name);
    this.books = ko.observableArray();

    _.each(booksToAdd, function(book){
        self.books.push(ko.observable(book));            
    });        
}   

var Book = function(author, title, genre) {
    this.author = ko.observable(author);
    this.title = ko.observable(title);
    this.genre = ko.observable(genre);
}

var PageViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.bookGroups = ko.observableArray();

    this.bookToUse = new Book("Robin Hobb", "Golden Fool", "Fantasy");

    this.indexAction = function() {
        var groups = [];

        var booksArray = [];

        booksArray.push(this.bookToUse);
        booksArray.push(new Book("Patrick  R Something", "Name Of The Wind", "Fantasy"));
        booksArray.push(new Book("Someone Else", "Game Of Thrones", "Fantasy"));

        groups.push(new BookGroup("To Read Now", booksArray));

        booksArray = [];

        booksArray.push(new Book("Terry Pratchett", "Color of Magic", "Discworld"));
        booksArray.push(new Book("Terry Pratchett", "Mort", "Discworld"));
        booksArray.push(new Book("Terry Pratchett", "Small Gods", "Discworld"));

        groups.push(new BookGroup("To Read Later", booksArray));
        this.bookGroups(groups);

    };

    this.handleButtonClick = function(){
        console.log(this.bookGroups()[0].books().length);
        this.bookGroups()[0].books().remove(this.bookToUse);
    };
};

viewModel = new PageViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.indexAction();
```

Why is remove not recognized here? Is this the right way to construct the model?

Many thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 errors:

- You tried to call remove function form javascript array instead observable array.
- You don't need to wrap book object with observable when put it to observableArray.

Comment: Thank you - I'm accepting this as the answer because you also explain that I don't need to wrap the book object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `remove` on the observableArray and not on its contents, in other words :

```
this.handleButtonClick = function(){ 
    console.log(this.bookGroups()[0].books().length); 
    this.bookGroups()[0].books.remove(this.bookToUse); 
};
```

see [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: This stops the error from happening. Then by changing how the books are added to the group makes the fiddle work. I'll make the changes in the fiddle to show what works. Thank you!